# Drools clear up working memory

Tags: java, drools

My web app has a feature for the user to take exam. And I use drools for evaluation of scores and gauge the knowledge level. I'm using stateful knowledge session. My case is something like this.

1. Every time the user take an exam there is 2 java beans inserted to the rules one is for evaluation of score and the other is for the result.
2. When the user finish up on an exam the result of the exam will be stored in the database.
3. After that the next user will go in the same cycle

My question is do I have to clear the working memory after the one user? If yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using stateful sessions, make sure you call `dispose()` after using them. Caching kbases is also recommended if possible, but creating them on demand should not leak memory anyway.

You should try  **profiling** to found any memory leak in Drools .

Other than that, it is just like any other java application. Use a profiler to find out what class (if any) is retaining your object instances in memory.

Comment: Can you give me a link about that **profiling**? I googled it I don't know which is that there. Sorry for this noob request.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/documents/tutorials/profilingtool/profilingexample_32.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are reusing the same ksession for all your exams, make sure to retract the facts you have inserted during the session execution. insertLogical() could be helpful in this case.

If you are using one session per exam, then just dispose the session after you use it.

Hope it helps,